# DatePicker CSS change when adding onSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH2RZ.png) for setting dates.
What I'm trying to do is opening the second datepicker after selecting a date on the first one. I'm using the onSelect function with jQuery like this :

```js
$('#dateDeb').datepicker({
 onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
  $("#dateFin").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
  setTimeout(function () {
   $("#dateFin").datepicker('show');
  }, 16);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="rechercheDate">Date facture : </label>
   <div class="col-sm-9" name="rechercheDate">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xl-2" style="margin-left: 0px">
     <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA !important;" id="dateDeb" class="form-control formRecherchePagesList" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: center"> - </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xl-2">
     <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA !important;" id="dateFin" class="form-control formRecherchePagesList" />
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label"> <input type="checkbox" id="ignDate" name="ignDate" checked="checked" /></label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <label for="ignDate" style="margin-top:5px">Ignorer les dates</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

No problem with this, it's working fine. My problem is that, when adding the onSelect event, the datepicker's CSS change from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCmYk.png) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZpQr.png).

Any solution ?

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: have you checked CDN's?

Comment: instead `$("#dateFin").datepicker('show');` try `$("#dateFin").show();`